# Import specific package

Tags: go, interface, package

I'm trying to solve a dependency problem : let's say I want to keep the code in my main.go totally decoupled from my database, I created 2 packages for that : dummy & postgres.

```
/app/
-- main.go

/dummy/
-- dummy.go

/postgres/
-- postgres.go
```

Everything is working fine, I just have to select in my main.go which package I would like to import to get a behavior or another... but is there a way to choose that when *building* main.go ?

If there's a more idiomatic way to achieve this, I'm of course very interested !

Comment: Finally I implemented the same kind of logic using a clean architecture. Here's a minimal example : https://github.com/Err0r500/cleanArchitectureGolang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize the Go conditional build via build tags and target your compilation of main.go.

Refer this [article](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/09/28/using-build-to-switch-between-debug-and-release) and put your thoughts into action.

**For Example:**

Directory structure

```
build-tags
├── build-tags
├── dummy
│   └── dummy.go
├── main_dummy.go
├── main_postgres.go
└── postgres
    └── postgres.go
```

**Sample implementation:**

dummy/dummy.go

```
package dummy

import "fmt"

func PrintName() {
    fmt.Println("My name is dummy package")
}
```

postgres/postgres.go

```
package postgres

import "fmt"

func PrintName() {
    fmt.Println("My name is postgres package")
}
```

main_dummy.go

```
// +build dummy

package main

import "build-tags/dummy"

func main() {
    dummy.PrintName()
}
```

postgres.go

```
// +build postgres

package main

import "build-tags/postgres"

func main() {
    postgres.PrintName()
}
```

Now let's build targeting `dummy` tag, same way you can do for `postgres` tag.

```
go build --tags="dummy"

# run the program
./build-tags

My name is dummy package
```